# Return deviant value from mean values in a graph

Tags: python, python-3.x, computer-vision

I have following file [data.txt](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XEgdFmvjI6dzRwm_P6hhfR3t_tp1ARm_/view?usp=sharing)

This file contains number of bounding boxes and their respective heights. I have wrote a function to extract the heights of all the boxes from json input data.txt respectively:

> heights [43, 17, 23, 24, 17, 27, 19, 19, 24, 22, 8, 8, 26, 25, 18, 19,
>   20, 20, 20, 21, 20, 20, 22, 18, 18, 19, 19, 16, 13, 20, 20, 19, 19,
>   20, 13, 20, 18, 18, 13, 12, 19, 25, 17, 13, 38, 38, 20, 19, 16]

I have wrote following script to plot the height of each box

```
box_number=[]
box_height=[]

for index2, num2 in enumerate(heights):
    print('box number',index2, 'box height',num2)
    box_number.append(index2)
    box_height.append(num2)


#ax = sns.lineplot(box_number, box_height); 
ax = sns.stripplot(box_number, box_height); 
ax.set(xlabel ='box number', ylabel ='height of box') 

# giving title to the plot 
plt.title('My first graph'); 

# function to show plot 
plt.show()
```

here's the output:

[image]

I want to write a function to print boxes which are very tall in height and which are deviant from the mean value of height . In short print box number 0,44 and 45. How can I do this?

(Every time I will get a different set of boxes but I'll have to find a mean value of their height and print boxes which are too tall)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several strategies to discover outliers. The definition of outlier is what matters at the end of the day. If you want a simple computation as you described, you can do something like this:

```py
import numpy as np

# heights
hs = [43, 17, 23, 24, 17, 27, 19, 19, 24, 22, 8, 8, 26, 25, 18, 19, 20, 20, 20, 21, 20,
      20, 22, 18, 18, 19, 19, 16, 13, 20, 20, 19, 19, 20, 13, 20, 18, 18, 13, 12, 19, 
      25, 17, 13, 38, 38, 20, 19, 16]

# let's say that an outlier is a height that is farther than 2*std from the mean
outliers_definition = np.abs(hs - np.mean(hs)) > 2 * np.std(hs)

# you can get their indexes this way
outliers_idx = np.argwhere(outliers_definition)

print(outliers_idx)
# array([[ 0],
#        [44],
#        [45]], dtype=int64)
```

Notice that the `mean` here is also taking the outliers into account. You could use the `median`, for example. If you want something more robust, there is a vast literature on outlier detection. I recommend you to take a look at it.